# Filter DataGridView rows range by 2 values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with this type of data:

[image]

I'd like to show only rows with HODD column value between 1.54 - 1.73.

How can I filter my DataGridView's values by that column's values?

I tried to find a solution online but I didn't find anything.

EDIT: This is the List code: http://pastebin.com/BijEWdRH

EDIT2: The Final solution:

```
decimal from = decimal.Parse(fromTxt.Text);
decimal to = decimal.Parse(toTxt.Text);
finabexDgv.DataSource = combinedDataList.Where(p => Convert.ToDecimal(p.HODD) >= from && Convert.ToDecimal(p.HODD) <= to).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you add the XAML of your GridView please?

Comment: @KOTIX Sorry, but what's a XAML?

Comment: @GrantWinney a List<T> :)

Comment: Oh sorry ! Thought you were doing WPF. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) could help I think !

Comment: @Marci we really need to know the datasource since you should filter the data instead of manipulate the rows of the grid. DataTables have a DataView property which has a RowFilter property. If its Enumerable you can just use a `where` clause in a Linq query.

Comment: @Crowcoder I edited my post with My code link. Check it please :)

Comment: @KOTIX Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alter your code like this to add the desired `where` "filter".

<strike>finabexDgv.DataSource = combinedDataList.where(p => p.HODD <= 1.54 && p.HODD >= 1.73).ToList();</strike>

**EDIT**
I corrected my example after noticing "where" is capitalized and HODD is a string, so it must be converted to a number. If any of your data in HODD is null or not a number, be aware this will throw an exception.

```
finabexDgv.DataSource = combinedDataList.Where(p => Convert.ToDecimal(p.HODD) >= 1.54m && Convert.ToDecimal( p.HODD) <= 1.73m ).ToList();
```

Comment: I changed your code because I got some errors, in this way:                 finabexDgv.DataSource = combinedDataList.Where(p => p.HODD <= 1,54 && p.HODD >= 1,73).ToList();
and now I got just one error: "The name 'p' doesn't exist in current context"
How Can I fix it, please? :)

Comment: This time I mocked up your code and noticed a couple things when I ran it, please see my edits.

Comment: from your solution I found a perfect solution. I put your code modified in my post. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) will get you to the results that you want. The example in there looks like a good tutorial on how you should use a `DataGridView` with filtering.

In the tutorial they show how to retrieve data from an XML source which is not your case. The following part is the useful one:

```
DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

// Create a DataGridView control and add it to the form.
DataGridView datagridview1 = new DataGridView();
datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
this.Controls.Add(datagridview1);

// Create a BindingSource and set its DataSource property to
// the DataView.
BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
source1.DataSource = view1;

// Set the data source for the DataGridView.
datagridview1.DataSource = source1;

//The Filter string can include Boolean expressions.
source1.Filter = "artist = 'Dave Matthews' OR cd = 'Tigerlily'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am using List than Xml and I should change all code :)

Comment: You don't have to change your List for an XML source. I just edited my answer to identify the useful part of the documentation for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting solution :)